How to beep from WSL?
How can I beep from WSL terminal?
Running on Windows 10 x64 with WSL2 running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Things I have tried that didn't work:
$ tput bel
$ echo -ne '\007'
$ echo -e "\a"

all produced no sound and no output.
$ echo -en "\a" > /dev/tty5
bash: /dev/tty5: Permission denied

error and no sound.
$ sudo apt install beep
$ beep
beep: Error: Could not open any device

error and no sound.
$ sudo apt install alsa-utils
$ speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 1

speaker-test 1.2.9

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Sine wave rate is 1000.0000Hz
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1342:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2721:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory

error and no sound.
$ sudo apt install sox
$ play -q -n synth 0.1 sin 880 || echo -e "\a"
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1342:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2721:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
play FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured

error and no sound.

The terminal bell is not a function of the operating system (WSL or otherwise) but the terminal. Which terminal emulator are you using?

@DanielB xfce4-terminal / bash

So is that xfce4-terminal via some X11 server on Windows? Or with WSLg?

@DanielB I don't know how it works, but on Windows Powershell I ran wsl --install Ubuntu-24.04 followed by wsl followed by sudo apt install xfce4-terminal , then xfce4-terminal appeared in my Windows start menu, and pressing on it in the start menu starts it.  (I can see in Process Explorer that it uses Microsoft Remote Desktop Client or msrdc.exe behind-the-scene but I don't know much more than that)

@DanielB wslg it is - the start menu shortcut expands to "C:\Program Files\WSL\wslg.exe" -d Ubuntu-24.04 --cd "~" -- xfce4-terminal

Having had time to try this myself, I can confirm that the audible bell is simply broken in GTK/VTE. This problem doesn’t appear to be restricted to WSL 2. gsound-play -i bell works after setting everything up, but the terminal doesn’t use it.

I hope someone comes up with a better solution making the standard echo -e "\a" work, but until then, this actually works for me:
$ sudo apt install pulseaudio-utils;
$ sudo wget --post-data='format=mp3&id=1417&button=Download' 'https://bigsoundbank.com/modules/telecharger.php' -O /usr/share/sounds/beep.mp3;
$ paplay /usr/share/sounds/beep.mp3;

I made a /usr/local/bin/beep
with the contents
#!/bin/sh
PULSE_SERVER=unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer paplay /usr/share/sounds/beep.mp3;

and chmod a+x. I set the PLUSE_SERVER env so that beep would work in sudo.
(why does PulseAudio player works when sox and alsa player does not? I don't know. Why does echo -ne '\007' not work? I don't know.)

$ grep bell-style ~/.inputrc -> set bell-style none ?

@Hannu grep: /home/hans/.inputrc: No such file or directory  but there is another file /etc/inputrc which contains comments about bell-style, but it does not actually contain not-commented-out lines about bell-style, hmm

Well, that gave you something to investigate ;-) - it was a long time since I last checked on how this is supposed to work; so can't help much more.

i have a note saying that bind -f ~/.inputrc will reload the settings from that file.

@Hannu unfortunately it didn't seem to work, at least set bell-style visible seems to make no difference

It might be WSL has missing (not implemented) features, this being one.
